# Wiring power to an Arduino compatible 5 V relay module?

Tags: relay

I asked a similar question a week ago but I don't think I was clear with it, so I thought I would try again as I am sure this SHOULD work but I do not know how to wire it up and hope someone can help.

In simple terms:

- I have a model railway DCC 4 block occupancy detector detection system ([BD4N](https://www.digitrax.com/products/detection-signaling/bd4n/)) that detects current on a wire and closes a loop on a +V input and an appropriate output. *This works*. On board LEDs indicate detection.
- The detection system (BD4N) requires an input voltage on the +common (+5 to 12 V) and when current is detected closes a loop to an appropriate output wire. I plan to use a +5 V power supply.
- I want to trigger a different system using a simple relay (it is also only 5 V,) so figured an Arduino compatible 4-pole 5 V relay board should work.
- When the output from the BD4N goes high (closes loop) I need it to trigger the input on a 4-pole relay board and this should trigger the relay open/closed.

**Here is where I am stuck**: This should be simple. How should I wire the power dupply (+5 V) to the telay board and the BD4N to make this work?

[image: My attempt at drawing the circuit but don't know where to connect +5v and +common]

My attempt at drawing the circuit but I don't know where to connect +5V and +common.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the output of the module is. It could very well be that your relay board is unsuitable.  I’d suggest you contact Digitrax.

Answer (score 0):

These relay units allow the relay coil supply (5v & Gnd) to drive the relay directly or alternatively (by changing jumper position (JDD-VCC Gnd)) to have the relay driven by an external 5v supply (for example if the driver circuit is current-limited).  The 5v supply should be connected to VCC and GND of the left hand pin arrangement, then the drive signal (low) for each relay is connected to the pin for each relay. If the JD jumper is left as shown, then a low signal on pin 1 will drive relay 1 on (and so on).  Your drive signal seems to be active high.  To drive these relays you need an active low.  You could either have the relays always on using your drive signal then off when the drive signal goes low, or invert the drive signal with a small switching transistor such as a BC547 wired as an inverter (for each channel).